# How to use actix_web::guard::Header?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

In order to support `application/json` and `multipart/form-data` on the same URL, I would like to check the "Content-Type" header and choose a proper `Data<T>` type to hand in to the `.data` function of `App::new`.

If I uncomment the `.guard` line, then `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F files=\"qqq\" localhost:8080/upload` is dropped. But without the `.guard` line all works as it was supposed. What is wrong?

```
HttpServer::new(move || {
    App::new()
        .service(resource("/upload")
     // .guard(actix_web::guard::Header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"))
        .data(form.clone())
        .route(post()
        .to(upload_multipart)
        )   
    )
})
```

How to join them properly in one instance of App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, actix-web 1.0.3 [does not support multipart/form-data](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/#form), but you can use [actix_multipart](https://docs.rs/actix-multipart/0.1.2/actix_multipart/struct.Multipart.html). Since the focus is deserializing same data with different content-types, I've simplified to using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

To support two different content-types, nest `web::resource` and add guards to each of the handlers:

```rust
web::resource("/")
    .route(
        web::post()
            .guard(guard::Header(
                "content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            ))
            .to(form_handler),
    )
    .route(
        web::post()
            .guard(guard::Header("content-type", "application/json"))
            .to(json_handler),
    ),
```

Create handlers that takes deserialized data, and send the data to a common handler:

```rust
fn form_handler(user: web::Form<User>) -> String {
    handler(user.into_inner())
}

fn json_handler(user: web::Json<User>) -> String {
    handler(user.into_inner())
}

fn handler(user: User) -> String {
    format!("Got username: {}", user.username)
}
```

Result:

```
$ curl -d 'username=adsf' localhost:8000
Got username: asdf⏎
$ curl -d '{"username": "asdf"}' localhost:8000
Parse error⏎
$ curl -d '{"username": "asdf"}' -H 'content-type: application/json' localhost:8000
Got username: asdf⏎
```

To create your own deserializer, implement the [`FromRequest`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/1.0.3/actix_web/trait.FromRequest.html) trait.

Comment: It is not what I want, because it does not solve problem of changing the parser of the body handed in `.data` method

Comment: You want to deserialize the body, with two different deserializers, depending on content-type?

Comment: Exactly. two different deserializers depending on content-type

Comment: I believe you should use two handlers then, each having it’s own guard. One handler using the [json extractor](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/#json), the other using the [form extractor](https://actix.rs/docs/extractors/#form). The handlers can be nested inside a `web::resource`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect my last comment.